# Generalize a reflection of a function over a line

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, curves, reflection

I want to write a parametric function that can take any function $f(x)$ and reflect it over a given line in the form $y=mx+b$ (excluding the vertical line).  I know the reflection matrix is given by:

$r_\theta=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\theta)
 &\sin(2\theta) \\ \sin(2\theta)
 & -\cos(2\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$

Where $\theta$ is the angle the line forms with the x-axis, in the case of lines passing through the origin.

This makes taking a function parameterized as $(t,f(t))$ under the reflection writable as:

$(x,f(t))\to(x\cos(2\theta)+f(t)\sin(2\theta),x\sin(2\theta)-f(t)\cos(2\theta)$

To write this in terms of a line, we can have the line $y=mx$. Where $m=\tan(\theta)$. And so the parameterized curve above gives the reflection of the function $f$ over the line $y$ for the angle the line forms with the x-axis.

I want to know if there is a way to generalize the parameterized curve to generalize for lines that don't necessarily pass through the origin, in the form $y=mx+b$, and write a general form for that transformation accounting for the intercept.

[image]

The rules I have been trying (the hidden curves in picture) work only for specific values for $\theta$, specifically for $\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n$.

Any help or even some insight for an approach would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at par. _Augmentted matrix_ in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix

Comment: Given what you already have, it's perhaps easiest to add $(0, -b)$ (translating the line to the origin), reflect, then add $(0, b)$ (to translate the line back to its original position).